Exchanging information between functions in C
I'm writing program in C, that goes with structure like this:
int main() 
{
 while(true)    
  {
   mousecommands();
   graphicupdate();
  }
}

Where each step in main is void function.
Simplified task that I want to achieve is:

mousecommands() detects where mouse is
graphicupdate() draws circle in that position.

To do this I need way to pass information from one function to another.
How should I do it?
Easier way would be global variables.
More clean would be to use variables in main and give pointers to them as arguments to each function. This is fine when each function passes information containing in variable or two, but not in twenty or so.
Thanks for all advice, cheers

Use pointer to structure with 20+ members.

As an added note: Presumably, with these function calls running in while (true) { ... } loop, you're counting on one of them to exit the program at some point. While this is certainly possible, you may want to instead return meaningful information on failures from any relevant functions. This can then be checked by the caller and handled as deemed appropriate at that time. That might mean printing an error to stderr and exiting, or it might mean retrying. This would give your program greater flexibility.

To illustrate @i486 comment:
struct MouseInfo { /* 7 members */ };
struct DisplayInfo { /* 16 members */ };
struct KeyboardInfo { /* 3 members */ };
struct AllInfo {
    struct MouseInfo *m;
    struct DisplayInfo *d;
    struct KeyboardInfo *k;
};

then pass around pointers to relevant structs, maybe to struct AllInfo if required.
int main(void) {
    struct AllInfo *a = initAll();
    mouse(a->m);
    circle(a->d, a->m);
    AllRelease(a);
}


fyi for OP - no need to use pointers. You could just struct AllInfo { struct MouseInfo m; and even just struct AllInfo a = initAll() and have everything allocated on stack without any malloc.

@KamilCuk yes, in this case, but if an initAll exists to create a new AllInfo struct, it's likely it does so via dynamic allocation to avoid copying the entire struct and to avoid lifetime issues.

Thanks for answers guys, structures required a bit f digging, but they're indeed best option here. And thanks for example too!
